Getting the next value of the same user if the type is "no type"
I'm trying to write a formula for this table that will show the subsequent value if a row containing the same user has "no type" as its type.
When Orange in column A, for instance, has a type of "no type" in column B, the result in column D will show "milk" since there is another Orange in row 4 that does not have a "no type" in column B.
If "no type" is selected, the value will remain unchanged.
In addition, the following user (apple, for example) will only replicate the user's type underneath it rather than the value above.



Name
Type
Result




Orange
No Type
Milk


Orange
No Type
Milk


Apple
Juice
Juice


Orange
Milk
Milk


Orange
No Type
No Type


Apple
No Type
Pie


Grapes
Wine
Wine


Apple
Pie
Pie


Apple
No Type
No Type



I tried using this formula,
=XLOOKUP(1, ([Name]= [@Name])*([Type]<>"No Type"),[Type], [Type])
However, all of the "No type" are changed regardless whether they are above or below.



Name
Type
MyFormula(not correct)
Expected Result




Orange
No Type
Milk
Milk


Orange
No Type
Milk
Milk


Apple
Juice
Juice
Juice


Orange
Milk
Milk
Milk


Orange
No Type
Milk
No Type


Apple
No Type
Juice
Pie


Grapes
Wine
Wine
Wine


Apple
Pie
Juice
Pie


Apple
No Type
Juice
No Type


Banana
Shake
Shake
Shake




=XLOOKUP(1;(A2:$A$11=A2)*(B2:$B$11<>"No Type");B2:$B$11;"No Type")


One way in powerquery is this, which temporarily changes No Type to null and takes advantage of fill...up... method
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index","No Type",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Type"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", {"Name"}, {{"data", each Table.ReplaceValue(Table.FillUp(_,{"Type"}),null,"No Type",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Type"}), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Type", "Index"}, {"Type", "Index"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"


